# Drools kie-maven-plugin error message using Gradle "plugin with id 'kie-maven-plugin' not found."

Tags: java, gradle, drools

I've gotten the kie-maven-plugin to work with maven, but when using it with gradle I get the error `plugin with id 'kie-maven-plugin' not found`.  I've added the `kie-maven-plugin` coordinates to both the plugin repository section as well as the project dependencies section with no luck (as well as either/or).  Am I getting the `apply plugin` line right?

In buildscript -> repositories -> dependencies section:

```
classpath 'org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.35.0.Final'
```

In allprojects section:

```
apply plugin: 'kie-maven-plugin'
```

In allprojects -> dependencies section:

```
compile group: 'org.kie', name: 'kie-maven-plugin', version: "7.35.0.Final"
```

I've also tried the following to no avail:

```
apply plugin: 'org.kie.maven.plugin'

apply plugin: 'kie'

apply plugin: 'org.kie'

apply plugin: 'org.kie.kie'

apply plugin: 'org.kie.kie-maven-plugin'

apply plugin: 'org.kie:kie-maven-plugin'

apply plugin: 'org.kie.maven.plugin.ValidateDMNMojo'
```